# system.reflection.targetinvocationexception in wp8

Tags: c#, asp.net, compiler-errors, windows-phone-8

I am getting this error in my code.
 Anybody knows how to solve this?
 As this problem  occurred in system.windows.ni.dll .

Comment: what are you doing (or trying to do) when you get this? what is the `.Message` of the exception? what is the `.InnerException` (if one)

Comment: your code threw a `TargetInvocationException`

Answer (score 4):

`TargetInvocation` just means that something was calling reflection `Invoke`, and the invoked method threw an exception. The real problem is hiding in the `.InnerException`. So you should `catch` the exception and inspect the `.InnerException` to see what is actually going wrong. Also look at the `.StackTrace`. of the `.InnerException` to see *where* it is going wrong.

Comment: ok but I am facing some System.ServiceModel.Communication exception in my project when I am trying to use wcf services in my windows phone app.  Please help.